# Lost bluetooth functionality after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, bluetooth, settings, bluez

A day ago or before I updated from 17.04 to 17.10, I was able to connect my computer with my headphones via bluetooth.  Now I can't.  I thought maybe I needed to install Bluetooth Manager and Bluetooth Adapter from the Software manager, but this didn't help.  Can someone suggest some code I can use through the terminal to reinstall the bluetooth drivers or whatever isn't working so I can get back to using the bluetooth function on my computer? ***On the settings, Bluetooth, it says plug in a dongle to use bluetooth now.  It didn't say this before.***

```
brian@brian-Gazelle-Professional:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
[sudo] password for brian: 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

brian@brian-Gazelle-Professional:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[ 1837.682565] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.629:112): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" pid=5534 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1837.739136] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.686:113): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=5536 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1837.796899] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.743:114): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.btmgmt" pid=5538 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1837.855706] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.802:115): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.btmon" pid=5540 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1837.906840] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.853:116): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hciattach" pid=5542 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1837.960018] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.906:117): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hciconfig" pid=5544 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1838.017010] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035362.963:118): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hcidump" pid=5546 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1838.071942] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035363.018:119): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hcitool" pid=5548 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1838.121894] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035363.068:120): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.obex" pid=5550 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1838.170836] audit: type=1400 audit(1509035363.117:121): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.obexctl" pid=5552 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: can you post the output of `sudo service bluetooth status` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Edit your post to include this info

Answer (score 3):

I've upgraded Kubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 yesterday.

Mostly the same issue for me, I'm no longer able to connect my bluetooth speaker (RYGHT TANK) even though my bluetooth service is running.

Here is my `sudo service bluetooth status` and `dmesg | grep -i blue` results:

```
soul@soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-10-27 23:50:19 CEST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 11613 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─11613 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

oct. 27 23:50:18 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
oct. 27 23:50:19 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[11613]: Bluetooth daemon 5.46
oct. 27 23:50:19 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
oct. 27 23:50:19 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[11613]: Starting SDP server
oct. 27 23:50:19 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[11613]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized

soul@soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   21.008903] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.008918] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.008920] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.008922] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.008927] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   31.455093] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.455095] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.455098] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  116.012720] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  116.012730] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  116.012738] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

A print screen of the message after trying to connect:
[connecting failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIUab.png)

Any idea?

EDIT (11/05):

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-11-05 09:42:42 CET; 7h ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 958 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─958 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

nov. 05 09:42:40 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
nov. 05 09:42:40 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: Bluetooth daemon 5.46
nov. 05 09:42:42 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: Starting SDP server
nov. 05 09:42:42 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
nov. 05 09:42:42 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
nov. 05 16:32:46 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for FC:58:FA:55:F4:68: Protocol not available
nov. 05 16:32:54 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for FC:58:FA:55:F4:68: Protocol not available
nov. 05 16:33:02 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[958]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for FC:58:FA:55:F4:68: Protocol not available
```

EDIT (11/05) (after having installed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth):

```
soul@soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90:~$ service bluetooth status
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-11-05 17:05:04 CET; 3min 32s ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 875 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
        Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─875 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

    nov. 05 17:04:57 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
    nov. 05 17:04:58 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Bluetooth daemon 5.46
    nov. 05 17:05:04 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
    nov. 05 17:05:04 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Starting SDP server
    nov. 05 17:05:05 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
    nov. 05 17:06:23 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    nov. 05 17:06:23 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    nov. 05 17:07:23 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
    nov. 05 17:07:23 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
    nov. 05 17:07:26 soul-ZBOX-ID88-ID89-ID90 bluetoothd[875]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

EDIT (11/05 got it!):
I ended up with a solution:

```
sudo apt install kmix
reboot
```

then

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
reboot
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

(last command may fail)

Then remove all your saved bluetooth devices and pair them again.

Do not forget to set the bluetooth devices at the top of the list of audio configuration: [image: Kmix configuration]

Comment: I cannot edit my message to add just "Hi" at the beginning of my question, so I say it here:Hi!

Comment: I have tried again to pair my speaker and noticed a difference on the result of the command `sudo service bluetooth status` (message edited)

Comment: next step... I've tried to install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` , and I was surprised that it wasn't already installed... anyway, the result is again different

Comment: So, is this a bug? Should a bug report be filed?

Comment: The problem occured after the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10. And my bluetooth worked correctly before upgrading.
I'd say yes, it's an upgrading bug, at least in my case.