# No Sound Upon 17.10 Upgrade

Tags: usb, sound, bluetooth, 17.10

I'm using a USB Bluetooth adapter for my computer to connect to my wireless headset (Mpow Jaws) ([https://www.amazon.com/Mpow-Bluetooth-Headphones-Wireless-Cancelling/dp/B01MDK0PIP?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MDK0PIP)). The USB Bluetooth adapter seems fine and can detect Jaws presence, but when I try to pair the two, the request is automatically denied.
[image: Pair Attempt]
I checked all of the usual Bluetooth related issues (Trying to pair when something is already paired (Although this headset does support multi-pair), power cycling the headset and trying again) I do believe that something is fishy with the OS because I got an unusual flag on the Bluetooth dash: [image: Weird Flag] I obviously pressed the Fix it button, but it came back the next time I opened the Bluetooth console. That and how fast it rejects the pair attempt. There is literally no time I can detect that it is legitimately trying to pair the headset, it auto rejects faster than a progress circle can appear.

**EDIT 0:** I upgraded from 17.04, and the Bluetooth Adapter/Headset pair worked fine.

**EDIT 1:** I also deleted the configuration from the Bluetooth console and re-scanned and attempted the pair again. It was able to detect the Headset, but no luck on the pair.

**EDIT 3:** It could be possible the the Bluetooth USB driver is out of date from the upgrade (And maybe something broke, but not so badly to cause failure in any noticeable way, aside from failure to connect devices), but I'm not sure what to do in such a case.

**EDIT 4:** This is the Bluetooth adapter: ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01BQO3QZO/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BQO3QZO)) it is a Costech 10/11m model.

**EDIT 5:** I just noticed that the entire sound driver system is missing. There appear to be no sound drivers.[image: Sound Drivers] This is bizarre because I have integrated speakers on my HP laptop and have USB speakers plugged in via, 3mm port.

**EDIT 6:** The sound works on a Kubuntu Live System USB stick of the same version number. I strongly believe that this is a sound issue rather than a bluetooth issue. The Bluetooth adapter is responsive and able to detect my Headset, however I think it breaks when it tries to integrate with the sound system and that's where the issue is arising from. Output of `lsmod` from USB Live System:

> `kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ lsmod
>   Module                  Size  Used by
>   rfcomm                 77824  14
>   cmac                   16384  1
>   bnep                   20480  2
>   usblp                  20480  0
>   cmdlinepart            16384  0
>   intel_spi_platform     16384  0
>   intel_spi              20480  1 intel_spi_platform
>   spi_nor                28672  1 intel_spi
>   mtd                    57344  4 spi_nor,intel_spi,cmdlinepart
>   intel_rapl             20480  0
>   x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
>   intel_powerclamp       16384  0
>   coretemp               16384  0
>   kvm_intel             200704  0
>   snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
>   arc4                   16384  2
>   snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
>   kvm                   581632  1 kvm_intel
>   snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
>   rtl8188ee              90112  0
>   rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
>   snd_hda_intel          40960  5
>   rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
>   irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
>
>   snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
>
>   mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee,rtlwifi
>
>   uvcvideo               90112  0
>
>   crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
>
>   crc32_pclmul           16384  0
>
>   ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
>
>   pcbc                   16384  0
>
>   snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
>
>   videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
>
>   videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
>
>   videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
>
>   videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
>
>   snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
>
>   videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
>
>   snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
>
>   btusb                  45056  0
>
>   btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
>
>   aesni_intel           188416  2
>
>   btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
>
>   btintel                16384  1 btusb
>
>   aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
>
>   media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
>
>   bluetooth             540672  41 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
>
>   crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
>
>   glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
>
>   snd_seq_midi           16384  0
>
>   snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
>
>   cfg80211              610304  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
>
>   cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
>
>   snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
>
>   snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
>
>   intel_cstate           20480  0
>
>   intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
>
>   hp_wmi                 16384  0
>
>   input_leds             16384  0
>   snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
>   joydev                 20480  0
>   sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
>   serio_raw              16384  0
>   wmi_bmof               16384  0
>   snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
>   ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
>   rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
>   memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
>   snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm
>   soundcore              16384  1 snd
>   hp_accel               28672  0
>   lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
>   mei_me                 40960  0
>   mei                    98304  1 mei_me
>   shpchp                 36864  0
>   ie31200_edac           16384  0
>   lpc_ich                24576  0
>   soc_button_array       16384  0
>   input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
>   intel_rst              16384  0
>   mac_hid                16384  0
>   intel_smartconnect     16384  0
>   hp_wireless            16384  0
>   parport_pc             32768  0
>   ppdev                  20480  0
>   lp                     20480  0
>   parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
>   ip_tables              24576  0
>   x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
>   autofs4                40960  2
>   overlay                73728  1
>   nls_utf8               16384  1
>   isofs                  45056  1
>   nls_iso8859_1          16384  0
>   dm_mirror              24576  0
>   dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
>   dm_log                 20480  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
>   uas                    24576  0
>   usb_storage            69632  2 uas
>   hid_generic            16384  0
>   usbhid                 49152  0
>   hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
>   i915                 1798144  20
>   nouveau              1638400  1
>   rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
>   mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
>   ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
>   i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 nouveau,i915
>   drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nouveau,i915
>   syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>   sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>   sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>   psmouse               147456  0
>   fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>   ahci                   36864  0
>   r8169                  81920  0
>   drm                   356352  11 nouveau,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
>   libahci                32768  1 ahci
>   rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
>   mii                    16384  1 r8169
>   video                  40960  2 nouveau,i915
>   wmi                    24576  4 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi
>   kubuntu@kubuntu:~$`

**Edit 7:** Upon executing `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio` & `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio` sound is restored, but there is no KDE sound icon in the system tray. Additionally, the volume up/down keys have no effect. Some packages from `kubuntu-desktop` are removed in the process. I though that by reinstalling them I could get the sound button back in the system tray, but the lack of audio issue comes back as well... Additionally sound devices play and are discoverable in the system settings/audio region.

These are the packages that are removed:

> `The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
>     pavucontrol-qt-l10n
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     alsa-base* kubuntu-desktop* pavucontrol-qt* plasma-pa* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth*
>     pulseaudio-module-gconf*
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

try to install kmix

```
sudo apt install kmix
reboot
```

you'll have the sound manager back.

However for the bluetooth I have the same issue: [Lost bluetooth functionality after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969595/lost-bluetooth-functionality-after-upgrading-from-17-04-to-17-10)

EDIT: Solution found (check out link above)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is caused by the recent [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1720519) and could be resolved by commenting the last 3 lines in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
###.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so 
###load-module module-switch-on-connect 
###.endif
```

To get KDE sound icon in the system tray and volume up/down keys working you need to install `plasma-pa`:

```
sudo apt install plasma-pa
```