# Ubuntu 17.10 Drivers Not Found/Working Properly?

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, 17.10

I recently upgraded from Kubuntu 17.04 -> 17.10 using the upgrade tool. All of my programs/settings/personalization is ok, but many of the drivers are either missing or nonfunctional. This includes sound (Both Integrated Speakers, USB Speakers, and Bluetooth Speakers) Additionally my USB Bluetooth adapter may be malfunctioning due to the driver([No Sound Upon 17.10 Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970055/mpow-jaws-bluetooth-headset-auto-rejection-upon-17-10-upgrade)).

This also includes my USB Wi-Fi adapter as well. The internal Wi-Fi card may still be disabled because I had to to enable the external USB one (Which has a higher range than my internal antenna. Basically all the steps we did to enable the USB antenna ([Wireless antenna does not appear despite its driver being installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932092/wireless-antenna-does-not-appear-despite-its-driver-being-installed/932286?noredirect=1#comment1554091_932286))

I should note that graphics drivers appear to be fine (At least from the System Settings Dash anyway.... I'm using an Nvidia graphics driver and all appears to be well on that frontier)

I'm still new to the upgrade, if I find anything else that broke, I'll post it.

**Edit 0:** I should note that the Wired connection that I'm using is ok, and that I can connect to the network from there, and that's how I'm making posts. Seeing a similar question to the Wi-Fi issue I went to ([No internet after upgrade to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967767/no-internet-after-upgrade-to-17-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and they linked me to (https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/645874) I attempted the fix and got a green status.[image: Green Status] The issue persists, although, granted I haven't had time to restart the system yet.

**Edit 1:**
I executed most of the lines from your solution, but hit a snag on the `dkms` region.

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo dkms uninstall rtl8812au/5.2.9
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo rm /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.9
rm: cannot remove '/usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.9': No such file or directory
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.9
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo rm -rf ~/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ rm -rf rtl8812au
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
Cloning into 'rtl8812au'...
remote: Counting objects: 607, done.
remote: Total 607 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 607
Receiving objects: 100% (607/607), 1.67 MiB | 10.32 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (250/250), done.
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo cp rtl8812au  /usr/src
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'rtl8812au'
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 4.2.2
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/8812au-4.2.2 does not exist.
```

I also tried a variation of it:

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2 does not exist.
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$
```

Comment: reboot. Many of those issues may be kernel related, you can also try an older kernel.

Comment: @Panther System was rebooted, issue still persists. Do you think that I should go to the last kernel that I used?

Comment: yes, please try an older kernel, one known good.

Comment: Are you trying to fix resolv or are you trying to install the wireless driver? If resolv is working in ethernet, i.e. you can reach the internet with ethernet, then resolv is working properly. Please clarify.

Comment: @chili555 The problem in the DNS fix wasn't the type of problem I was having. It was just the fix that another person recommended for Wi-Fi issues after upgrading. I'm looking to restore Wi-Fi capability and sound. I'll try the previous kernel.

Comment: @Panther I'm using Kernel 4.10.0-041000-generic (From uname -r) and the issue still persists.

Comment: Is this the wireless that you want to activate per `lsusb`? ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Comment: @chili555 Got: `Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
` Yes, it is.

Comment: Have you tried booting with a 17.10 live system (eg on a USB pen-drive), if it works there you can `lsmod` and see what kernel modules are in use. FWIW I always wait at least a month when there's a new release unless I want to spend time fixing a system, YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a working internet connection, open a terminal and enter these commands one at a time:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install git
```

If it is already installed, please just continue.

First, let's clean away the steps that we've shown are not working:

```
sudo dkms uninstall rtl8812au/5.2.9
sudo rm /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.9
sudo rm ~/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9
rm -rf rtl8812au
```

Next, please do:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: This was done in the 4.10 kernel, but it still doesn't work. I can reattempt in the newer kernel if you want.

Comment: Please do and note my edit above in a few moments. I don't think you used the *zebulon2* git repository previously, however.

Comment: I'm guessing that I did, because I got an error message suggesting that I did after executing the first line `fatal: destination path 'rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: No effect on either kernel.

Comment: Yes, I repeated all steps in your post after edit. This included the Zebulon 2 directory.

Comment: When you encounter an error in any step, all further steps will be errors, too and ineffective. Please try again but start with: `cd ~ && rm -rf rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9` Then git clone and so on.

Comment: Please see my completely redone answer above in a few minutes!

Comment: I hit a snag with `dkms`. I posted the Konsole output.  I'll try pbhj's suggestion and try to get the modules loaded if the USB live system works out.

Comment: I have edited the `cp` step and all following a bit, please try again.

Comment: Yep, it looks like the USB Wi-Fi Adapter is back to operational status. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried this `sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
` on my desktop lab computer downstairs running Kubuntu 18.04 and got `ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64)
` It seems like it installed partially.

Comment: In your desktop device downstairs, do you have the exact same device? Did you follow all the steps, starting with "git clone"?

Comment: Yep, same device, instructions followed. Should I make a new post?

Comment: Yes, please and show the result of each command as well as: `sudo dkms status` If the output is lengthy, paste it here and give us the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: `rtl8812au, 4.2.2: added
rtl8812AU, 5: added
`

Comment: As I suggested, please start a new question and include all of this in the question.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your new post.

Comment: Posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045765/usb-antenna-not-working-on-dell-optiplex-760-desktop

Comment: This solution worked fine for me in Ubuntu 18.04, thank you! @chili555 Is it something "special" with the 4.2.2 repo you linked to? I first tried "with apt install rtl8812au-dkms" but that did not work at all.

Comment: @jimutt I suspect it is that the dkms version in the repos doesn't include your exact usb.id. We'd have to check to verify exactly but as long as it's now working for you, I assume it's all good.